# How to can I cause an exit, from a script that receives data through a pipe, from another program?

Tags: bash, process, pipe

I have Bash script that is used to process data, which is sent through a pipe from another process.

I'm trying to add a functionality that causes and exits after a certain condition is met, whose simplified representation is:

```bsh
( while true; do date; sleep 1; done ) | ( for ((i = 0; i < 3; i++)); do read -r line; echo LINE: $line; sleep 1; done; exit 1 )
```

In the real case:

- the command after the pipe is included in (and replaced by) a script;
- the command before the pipe is a binary executable, and I don't have control over its internals.

I've also tried to close stdin:

```bsh
( while true; do date; sleep 1; done ) | ( for ((i = 0; i < 3; i++)); do read -r line; echo LINE: $line; sleep 1; done; exec 0<&- )
```

However, when the condition is met, nothing is sent to stdout, but the left program still runs.

How can I accomplish the task?

Comment: You must close standard output in the program which is pumping data into the pipe, that it, on the left of the `|` symbol. Otherwise, you must [`break`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) the `for` loop when the condition is met.

Comment: @AlexP thanks. I've made a clarification - I don't have control over the command before the pipe.

Comment: Well then, it depends on what exactly you want to do. For example, you could timeout reading from standard input if no more data is received after 5 seconds. The point being that you need to define your problem exactly and document your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your pipeline does not exit is that the `exit 1` statement only terminates the right hand side subshell.

After the right hand side has exit, the `date` command that you use for generating data will start failing since it can't write its output to anywhere (it would be killed by a `PIPE` signal). You don't test the exit status of `date`, so you don't see this.

Rewriting the left hand side as either

```bash
(
    while true; do
        if ! date; then
            exit    # or: break
        fi
        sleep 1
    done
)
```

or as

```bash
(
    while date; do
        sleep 1
    done
)
```

will make the pipeline as a whole behave as you expect.

This is indicative of the data-producing binary that you have on the left hand side of your pipeline not checking whether writes are successful or not (and it may also ignore the `PIPE` signal).  Closing standard input in the right hand side subshell would not help (this is already done when you exit that subshell anyway).

This is a bug in the program that produces the data.

How can you work around that?

One way would be to use a named pipe.  This would allow you the fetch the PID of the data-producing process, which you can later use to kill it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

rm -f data.pipe
mkfifo data.pipe

( while true; do date; sleep 1; done ) >data.pipe & pid=$!

(
    for ((i = 0; i < 3; i++)); do
        read -r line
        printf 'LINE: %s\n' "$line"
        sleep 1
    done
    kill "$pid"
    exit 1
) <data.pipe
```

If the program is ignoring the `PIPE` signal, it may well be ignoring other signals, so you would have to experiment with sending it the default `TERM` first and if that does not work, try `INT` etc.